# Can no longer create a packageloader in jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

When I try to create a packageLoader in Jinja2 with:

```
loader=jinja2.PackageLoader( 'cyan', 'templates')
```

I get an error:

```
In [2]: loader=PackageLoader( 'cyan', 'templates')                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/work/venvs/CYAN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    358     try:
--> 359         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    360     except KeyError:

KeyError: 'cyan'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9f5a5a8d0f55> in <module>
----> 1 loader=PackageLoader( 'cyan', 'templates')

~/work/venvs/CYAN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py in __init__(self, package_name, package_path, encoding)
    222         from pkg_resources import DefaultProvider, ResourceManager, \
    223                                   get_provider
--> 224         provider = get_provider(package_name)
    225         self.encoding = encoding
    226         self.manager = ResourceManager()

~/work/venvs/CYAN/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    359         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    360     except KeyError:
--> 361         __import__(moduleOrReq)
    362         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]
    363     loader = getattr(module, '__loader__', None)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cyan'
```

This USED to work. I haven't figured out what recent change could have caused this. There is a templates directory, it has **init**.py.

This: [HTML templating using Jinja2 No module named your app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855933/html-templating-using-jinja2-no-module-named-your-app) looks like the same issue, but the suggestion is to not use PackageLoader. Since my code WORKED 2 weeks ago, I'm concerned that I broke something else, and this is just a symptom, so I'd rather not just make the symptom go away, if I can figure out what is actually happening.

The extra weird thing about this is that 'cyan' is the name of the program. In the documentation, it uses "yourapplication" so I assumed it could be any string, and was using it to name things internally...

Comment: Do you have any `cyan.py` file in same directory or in PYTHONPATH?

Comment: No. should I? GAH! I created an empty cyan.py, and now it works!

Comment: Should I answer this question or not?

Comment: yes please! that solved the problem! I had a bogus cyan.py that I deleted, because no one was calling it... D'oh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error showing that :

> 359-->  **module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]**

There is an error in same line because when we execute the following code:

```py
>> import sys
>> module = sys.modules
```

the variable module is a dictionary of `key:<ModuleName>` and `value:<ModuleObject>`

as per your code you were trying to fetch the `cyan` module from above dictionary object but there is no any key that can match with your module name "cyan" because `cyan.py` is neither in your local directory nor in your SYSTEM-PATH.

**Creating a module named `cyan.py` in same directory or in module path for python will fetch one more module in your dictionary object and now you can call it using `sys.modules['cyan']`.**

Comment: The problem was that 'cyan' is actually the name of the suite, not an individual program... so there was no cyan.py... or rather, at one point there was, but it was superfluous, so I deleted it... oops...